# Como criar Array associativos em javascript, json, como manipular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, array-associativo

É a primeira vez que estou lidando com essa situação, então não sei exatamente como contornar. O fato é o seguinte, possuo um formulário com diversos inputs, divididos por seções:
[image: Imagem do formulário seccionado por tabs]

Na Tab Experiencia, eu preencho alguns inputs com os dados e ao clicar em adicionar eu crio blocos com os dados preenchidos da seguinte forma:

```
$('#'+destino).append(
    "<div class='blococurso box-experiencia'>"
    +"<label>Empresa:</label> <span class='content' data-content="+experiencia.empresa+">"+experiencia.empresa+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Cargo:</label> <span class='content' data-content="+experiencia.cargo+">"+experiencia.cargo+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Admissão:</label> <span class='content' data-content="+experiencia.admissao+">"+addDemissao.admissao.toString().replace(/,/g, '/')+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Demissão:</label> <span class='content' data-content="+experiencia.demissao+">"+addDemissao.demissao.toString().replace(/,/g, '/')+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Atividades:</label> <span class='content' data-content="+experiencia.atividades+">"+experiencia.atividades+"</span><br>"
    +"<i class='fa fa-close btn-fechar fechar-experiencia' data-destino='' data-funcao='remover'></i></div>"
  );
```

Ao clicar no botão salvar dados, eu pego todos os inputs e coloco em obj javascript, e os dados como estes da experiência que estão em Divs, eu pego assim:

`$("#painel-experiencia .box-experiencia .content").each(function(index){
      experiencia.push( $(this).text() );
    });`

Neste momento eu tenho um Array semelhante a isso;
.`["dasd", "asdas", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "dasdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "asdasdaasd", "asdasda", "asdasd", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "dsadasdas"]`

Porém o que eu preciso está mais para isso:
.`[{"empresa": "asdas", "admissao": "01/01/2017", "demissao": "01/01/2017", "atividades":"dasdasd"}, {"empresa": "asdas", "admissao": "01/01/2017", "demissao": "01/01/2017", "atividades":"dasdasd"}]`

O que eu busco é um array associativo e uma forma de adicionar cada bloco de experiencia como um array, dentro de um array wrapper. O que eu preciso está mais para json, se essa é a unica forma, como inserir os dados dentro de um Json e depois embrulha-lo num outro json?

Se souberem de outra forma de chegar ao mesmo fim seria de muita ajuda.

Comment: Funciona bem a parte de preencher os inputs?

Comment: @Sergio♦, desculpa não entendi, preencher os inputs "empresa, cargo etc" se sim, o preenchimento está normal, na imagem que eu anexei os dados que estão à direita são dados inseridos pelos inputs.

Comment: Testaste/compreendeste a minha resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que isso possa lhe ajudar.

No seu código inclua uma informação no span para utilizar como chave (data-chave) no dicionário.

```
$('#'+destino).append(
    "<div class='blococurso box-experiencia'>"
    +"<label>Empresa:</label> <span class='content' data-chave='empresa' data-content="+experiencia.empresa+">"+experiencia.empresa+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Cargo:</label> <span class='content' data-chave='cargo' data-content="+experiencia.cargo+">"+experiencia.cargo+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Admissão:</label> <span class='content' data-chave='admissao' data-content="+experiencia.admissao+">"+addDemissao.admissao.toString().replace(/,/g, '/')+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Demissão:</label> <span class='content' data-chave='demissao' data-content="+experiencia.demissao+">"+addDemissao.demissao.toString().replace(/,/g, '/')+"</span><br>"
    +"<label>Atividades:</label> <span class='content' data-chave='atividades' data-content="+experiencia.atividades+">"+experiencia.atividades+"</span><br>"
    +"<i class='fa fa-close btn-fechar fechar-experiencia' data-chave='empresa' data-destino='' data-funcao='remover'></i></div>"
);
```

Reescreva a sua função que salva dessa forma:

```
function salvar(){
    experiencias = Array();
    $(".box-experiencia").each(function(index, obj){
        experiencia = {}
        $(".content", obj).each(function(index1, obj1){
          experiencia[$(obj1).attr('data-chave')] =  $(obj1).text();
        });
        experiencias.push(experiencia);
    });
    console.log(experiencias);
}
```

O primeiro selector, $(".box-experiencia").each, busca apenas as divs e itera cada uma. O segundo seletor busca cada span dentro da div atual e monta um dicionario com as informações. Ao final, o dicionário é incluído no array de experiências.

Veja o exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/3h1oafqc/13/

Comment: perfeito cara, exatamente isso. Mais uma dúvida, quando você atribui experiencia[$(obj1).attr('data-chave')] = $(obj1).text(); Você está criando um dicionário que seria um array associativo, em que o índice é definido pelo atributo 'data-chave' e depois adiciona o valor pelo .text()?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente. Como exemplo, se você fizesse manualmente seria algo assim: 
 
 experiencia = Array();
 experiencia['empresa']='teste';

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado, brother! @fsola

Answer (score 1):

Para mostares um objeto com os valores desses inputs substitui

```
experiencia.push($(this).text());
```

por

```
experiencia.push({[this.dataset.content]: $(this).text()});
```

Porem essa notação para atribuir chaves a objetos com `[]` na criação é muito recente e o suporte pode ser fraco, por isso podias fazer assim:

```
var dados = $("#painel-experiencia .box-experiencia .content").get().reduce(function(obj, el){
    obj[el.dataset.content] = $(el).text();
    return obj;
}, {});
```